# Apache Netbeans Output Window showing more than result

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11, output-window

Is it possible to customize the output window on Apache Netbeans to make it show the result only?
Like e.g.

run-single:
Hello World

I mean what are these informations and why?

[image: Netbeans output Window]

Comment: you show no code, you don't show your configuration, yet you expect us to explain it's behavior?

Comment: What kind of code do you need there is only System.out.println("Hello World"); including class and main method. I don't get it?!

Comment: so .. there is no ant config? basically, what is shown there, is the terminal of your ide, so it also tends to print some config your ide does. If you have it in a .jar file which you execute from command line, you'll likely to get a different result

Comment: Thank you anyways for the effort to answer. I think I'm going to install Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an Ant java project. You can adjust the Ant verbosity in Netbeans menu Tools/Options/Java/Ant, set Verbosity Level to "Quiet".